# Containers can't connect to each other in swarm mode in multi-host environment

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-swarm

I am running 3 nodes on DigitalOcean (1GB, with private-networking) and after deploying this stack, containers can't connect to other containers using host aliases.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      mynet:
        aliases:
          - mongo
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      mynet:
        aliases:
          - redis
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]

  app:
    image: node
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    networks:
      - mynet
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]

networks:
  mynet:
```

### Problem

```
root@mongo-container:/# ping mongo # works
root@mongo-container:/# ping redis # doesn't work

root@redis-container:/# ping redis # works
root@redis-container:/# ping mongo # doesn't work

root@app-container:/# ping mongo # doesn't work
root@app-container:/# ping redis # doesn't work
```

### Configuration

**daemon.json**

```
{ "userland-proxy": false }
```

**`docker version`:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:50:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:50:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: Can I know why this question was down voted?

Comment: Can you double-check the status of the "mynet" network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31238) in Docker Swarm mode, and it is fixed in upcoming release of Docker [v17.04.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/milestone/60)